# grouping & summing similar values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, defaultdict

I have data in this format:

```
d = [
 {'key': '2018-05-10', 'vals': {'Clicks': 229, 'Link Clicks': 210}},
 {'key': '2018-05-11', 'vals': {'Clicks': 365, 'Link Clicks': 379}},

 {'key': '2018-05-10', 'vals': {'Clicks': 139, 'Link Clicks': 11}},
 {'key': '2018-05-11', 'vals': {'Clicks': 1348, 'Link Clicks': 73}},

]
```

i.e, it has multiple entries with same `key`

I want it to group it so that `Clicks` & `Link Clicks` are summed for common dates:

So output should be like:

```
d = [
 {'key': '2018-05-10', 'vals': {'Clicks': 368, 'Link Clicks': 221}},
 {'key': '2018-05-11', 'vals': {'Clicks': 1713, 'Link Clicks': 452}},
]
```

I thought of first grouping values together by using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

    dd = defaultdict(list)

    for i in d:                        
        dd[i['key']].append(i['vals'])
```

which gives the following output:

```
{ 2018-05-10': [
             {'Clicks': 229, 'Link Clicks': 210},
             {'Clicks': 139, 'Link Clicks': 11}
              ],
 '2018-05-11': [
             {'Clicks': 365, 'Link Clicks': 379},
             {'Clicks': 1348, 'Link Clicks': 73}
             ]}
```

Now I think I can use `Counter` to sum up values but I am getting it how to do. Also the names of keys, i.e. `Clicks` & `Link Clicks` might change & `vals` can have more than 2 entries.

Also can it be done without using `defaultdict`? Is there any better method?

***NOTE: I think using this method of defaultdict is not good as as i always want data to be sorted by date and as soon as i use dict i will loose order***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter, OrderedDict
ld = [{'key': '2018-05-10', 'vals': {'Clicks': 229, 'Link Clicks': 210}}, {'key': '2018-05-11', 'vals': {'Clicks': 365, 'Link Clicks': 379}}, {'key': '2018-05-10', 'vals': {'Clicks': 139, 'Link Clicks': 11}}, {'key': '2018-05-11', 'vals': {'Clicks': 1348, 'Link Clicks': 73}}]
out=defaultdict(Counter())
for d in ld:
    out[d['key']].update(d['vals'])

new = OrderedDict(sorted(out.items()))
print(new)
# OrderedDict([('2018-05-10', Counter({'Clicks': 368, 'Link Clicks': 221})), ('2018-05-11', Counter({'Clicks': 1713, 'Link Clicks': 452}))])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

d = {
'2018-05-10': [
             {'Clicks': 229, 'Link Clicks': 210},
             {'Clicks': 139, 'Link Clicks': 11}
              ],
 '2018-05-11': [
             {'Clicks': 365, 'Link Clicks': 379},
             {'Clicks': 1348, 'Link Clicks': 73}
             ],
}

m = OrderedDict()
for k, v in d.items():
    m[k] = Counter()
    for i in v:
        m[k].update(i)
    m[k] = dict(m[k])
    # or if you want to keep the 'vals' key and list:
    # m[k] = [{"vals": dict(m[k])}]

pprint(m)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('2018-05-11', {'Clicks': 1713, 'Link Clicks': 452}),
             ('2018-05-10', {'Clicks': 368, 'Link Clicks': 221})])
```

Comment: but i want dates to be in sorted order always.

Comment: I edited to use `OrderedDict` to have sorted dictionary.

Comment: `d` was generated using `defaultdict(list)` as in my question so the order information as lost there itself?

Comment: Could be, depends on the version of python you use. Only recent versions of Python have the `dict` sorted by default.

Comment: so how can i approach the solution ?i am using python version 2.7

Comment: So don't use `defaultdict` but `OrderedDict` and you need to add values to this `OrderedDict` already sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested dictionary comprehension. The relevant `c_type` keys, i.e. `Clicks` & `Link Clicks`, are derived from the first list for each date. Otherwise, the method will naturally accept any number of categories.

```
res = {k: {'vals': {c_type: sum(item[c_type] for item in v) for c_type in v[0]}}
       for k, v in dd.items()}

{'2018-05-10': {'vals': {'Clicks': 368, 'Link Clicks': 221}},
 '2018-05-11': {'vals': {'Clicks': 1713, 'Link Clicks': 452}}}
```

Comment: will dates always be in sorted order? i need that so the output should be a list of dictionaries i guess? i have updated the question with this information

Comment: @anekix, Dictionaries are considered unordered (unless you have Python 3.7+). If you are using Python 3.6 or lower, you should use `collections.OrderedDict` to define an order.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that instead of your output format being a list of dictionaries where every dictionary only has keys (`key`:`vals`), you should just have an actual dictionary of `{key: vals}` pairs!

This makes the code cleaner and more readable as well as making accessing a specific date neater as you don't need to loop through the list (`O(n)`), you can just access that date directly and get the clicks.

So, for instance:

```
dates = {}
for dd in d:
    dates.setdefault(dd['key'], []).append(dd['vals'])

dates = {k: {kk:sum(dd[kk] for dd in v) for kk in v[0].keys()} \
                                        for k,v in dates.items()}
```

which gives:

```
{
  "2018-05-10": {
    "Clicks": 368,
    "Link Clicks": 221
  },
  "2018-05-11": {
    "Clicks": 1713,
    "Link Clicks": 452
  }
}
```

and now you can get the data for a specific date directly with something like:

```
dates['2018-05-11']['Clicks']
#1713
```

---

If you require a list of sorted dictionaries (by date), then we can just take our current dictionary and index each date in the original data as that appears to already be sorted:

```
order = [dd['key'] for dd in d]
date_list = sorted([{'key':k,'vals':v} for k,v in dates.items()], \
                                       key=lambda dd: order.index(dd['key']))
```

which gives `date_list` as a date-ordered list:

```
[
  {
    "key": "2018-05-10",
    "vals": {
      "Clicks": 368,
      "Link Clicks": 221
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "2018-05-11",
    "vals": {
      "Clicks": 1713,
      "Link Clicks": 452
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: i want the data to be always sorted by date. i have updated the quesyion with this information

Comment: @anekix updated - you now have the ability to access a specific date quickly with with the `dates` dictionary or iterate over them sorted with `date_list` :)

Answer (score 1):

We can generalize this to a basic "group-fold" approach:

```
from operator import add, itemgetter

def group_fold(data, fold=add, key=itemgetter('key'), vals=itemgetter('vals')):
    result = {}
    for entry in data:
        ky = key(entry)
        vlb = vals(entry)
        vla = result.get(ky, None)
        if vla:
            for subk, subv in vl.items():
                if subk in vla:
                    vla[subk] = fold(vla[subk], subv)
                else:
                    vla[subk] = subv
        else:
            result[ky] = dict(vlb)
    return result
```

We can thus now use this as `group_fold(d)`, but we can customize the fold function, for example to `mul`tiply instead of `add`:

```
from operator import mul

group_fold(d, fold=mul)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

```
d = [
{'key': '2018-05-10', 'vals': {'Clicks': 229, 'Link Clicks': 210}},
{'key': '2018-06-01', 'vals': {'Clicks': 365, 'Link Clicks': 379}},

{'key': '2018-05-10', 'vals': {'Clicks': 139, 'Link Clicks': 11}},
{'key': '2018-06-01', 'vals': {'Clicks': 1348, 'Link Clicks': 73}},

]

final_dict = {}

for doc in d:
    date = doc['key']

    if date not in final_dict:
        final_dict[date] = {}

        for key in doc['vals']:
            final_dict[date][key] = doc['vals'][key]

    else:

        for key in doc['vals']:
            final_dict[date][key] += doc['vals'][key]


resp_dict = [{date: final_dict[date]} for date in sorted(final_dict)]

print resp_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested defaultdict:

```
result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for entry in d:
  for key, val in entry['vals'].items():
    result[entry['key']][key] += val
```

It will give you this result:

```
{"2018-05-10": {"Clicks": 368, "Link Clicks": 221}, "2018-05-11": {"Clicks": 1713, "Link Clicks": 452}}
```

Comment: see my edit in question. the dates should be in order as in the original data.using a `dictionary` will loose order information

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
d =  [
 {'key': '2018-05-10', 'vals': {'Clicks': 368, 'Link Clicks': 221}},
 {'key': '2018-05-11', 'vals': {'Clicks': 1713, 'Link Clicks': 452}},
]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
newdict={}
for dt, k in groupby(sorted(d,key=itemgetter('key')),key=itemgetter('key')):
    for d in k:
        newdict[dt]=d['vals']
```

**Output:**

```
{'2018-05-10': {'Clicks': 368, 'Link Clicks': 221},
 '2018-05-11': {'Clicks': 1713, 'Link Clicks': 452}}
```

Comment: see the edit in my question. the dates should be in order

Comment: @min2bro: but here you retain the last occurrance, you do *not* sum up the values?